# Memory issue for bing map control

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application the memory usage becomes high when navigating from a page having map control.Is there any way to reduce memory usage for bing map control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that a reference to the Map control is maintained after you navigate back to the previous page. In addition to freeing any references, I found that using the SetMode method also helps free up the references :-

```
map1.SetMode(new NullMode(), false);
```

I think I used the following forum post as a reference (it was a while ago) :-

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65180/463528.aspx

In my case I had to do some additional cleanup and change to code structure with relation to using triggers and unregistring the MVVM Light Messenger.