# Windows Phone 7 Bing Map Memory Rise

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a strange problem with memory leaks and BingMap control on WP7. In my application the memory usage becomes high when navigating from a page having map control. I clear all references, events, set map mode to NullMode etc. like it is said in this issue [Memory issue for bing map control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433340/memory-issue-for-bing-map-control) but it does not work for me. I tried with blank page and map only and the problem still exists. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Bing Maps control in WP7. Try using the maps in WP8/8.1